# PHP Singleton pattern, fatal error when calling getter

Tags: php, mysqli, null, singleton, getter

I am pretty new to PHP and try to learn it the OOP way as I have an understanding of it. My problem is I have no idea why I am getting the null error below when I try to get the mysqli connection.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getConn() on
>   null

```
    <?php

class ConnectDB
{
    private $conn;


    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'gs');
        $this->checkConnection();
    }

    public function getConn()
    {
        return $this->conn;
    }

    /**
     * @return ConnectDB
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        static $instance = null;
        if($instance == null)
        {
            $instance == new ConnectDB();
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    public function checkConnection()
    {
        if($this->conn->connect_errno)
        {
            echo "Can't connect to Database: " .mysqli_connect_error();
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Connected!";
        }

    }

}

$conn = ConnectDB::getInstance()->getConn();
```

Comment: This is just a typo - `$instance == new ConnectDB();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getInstance` method, where you create the class instance you wrote `$instance == new ConnectDB();`. Use a single `=` for assignments.

I don't think that your `getInstance` method is a singleton at all. You are initializing the variable `$instance` in every call to `null`, so you should get a new instance every time.

Try it like this:

```
class ConnectDB
{
    private $conn;
    private static $instance = null;
    ...
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(self::$instance == null)
        {
            self::$instance == new ConnectDB();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I feel ashamed right now. Such a silly mistake and kept me confused for hours and i didn't even notice.

Comment: As of static $instance = null inside the getInstance function, i thought in PHP static variables are initialized only on first function call. Is this not the case?

Comment: Just tested your code on my machine and it works indeed. I never used that syntax. You never stop learning :)

Answer (score 0):

See if you can make this work:

```
<?php

class ConnectDB {
    private $_connection;
    private static $_instance; //The single instance
    private $_host = "localhost";
    private $_username = "root";
    private $_password = "root";
    private $_database = "gs";

    // 
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$_instance) { // If no instance then make one
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    // Constructor
    private function __construct() {
        $this->_connection = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username, $this->_password, $this->_database);

        // Error handling
        if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
            trigger_error(
                "Failed to conencto to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error(),E_USER_ERROR
            );
        } else{
            echo "Connected!";
        }
    }


    private function __clone() { }


    public function getConn() {
        return $this->_connection;
    }

    $db = ConnectDB::getInstance();
    $mysqli = $db->getConn(); 

}
?>
```